# longitudinal calculation in SAS with lag function

Tags: sas

Hi I have a data in columns., and the patient visits

some patient visits have not recorded the values., and I want to copy the previous visit values., and I am using the lag function which is not working any idea?

the data is something like this

```
ID value 
A   22
A   . 
A   23
B   . 
B   12
C   3
C  .
C  .
C  .
C  21
```

the required output.,

```
ID value 
A   22
A   22 
A   23
B   23 
B   12
C   3
C   3
C   3
C   3
C  21
```

Comment: Can you post the code?

Comment: Ahah, finally found the duplicate.  Need better search terms.

Answer (score 2):

You would use RETAIN not LAG here. 
Retain:

```
data want;
 set have;
 retain newval;
 if not missing(oldval) then newval=oldval;
run;
```

If you need the same variable name, drop+rename to get `newval` into `oldval` name.

Normally, you would also check for ID to be the same; your example updates across IDs, so I leave that out, but if you don't want to update a `b` record with `a` value, you need to add a `by id;` and then `if first.id then call missing(newval);` to reset it at the start of each new ID.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that the `ID` field represents your patient ID?  And that you don't want to use values recorded against patient A for patient B etc...   If so, then this code will do the job:

```
data test;
  infile datalines truncover;
  input ID $ value ;

datalines;
A 22
A  
A 23
B  
B 12
C 3
C  
C  
C  
C 21
;
run;
```

Sort it first so that we can use by-group processing:

```
proc sort data=test;
  by id;
run;
```

I prefer to use the `retain` statement rather than the `lag()` function as people are less likely to make mistakes using `retain`:

```
data final;
  set test;
  by id;

  retain prev_value .;

  if first.id then do;
    prev_value = .;  * RESET THIS VALUE EVERY TIME WE GET TO A NEW PATIENT;
  end;

  if value eq . then do;
    value = prev_value; * VALUE IS MISSING SO ASSIGN THE PREVIOUS RECORDED VALUE FOR THE PATIENT AGAINST IT;
  end;
  else do;
    prev_value = value; * PATIENT HAS A NEW VALUE TO RECORD SO SAVE IT INTO THE PREV_VALUE VARIABLE;
  end;

run;
```

Incidentally this will give a slightly different result to what you requested as patient B did not supply a value on his first visit so his first record will remain null.  If you need to fill that in with the value from his second visit, simply sort the dataset in the opposite direction, and run the same code against it.

Comment: thank you so much Robert., it solved my problem., I was facing the problem with the values copying from the previous ID., but this worked Amazing., !Thanks a lot